# How to transmit $data to function with gridview

Tags: function, gridview, yii

I have model `DangTuyen` and function

```
public function statusImageAccept($status) {
        $str = "";

        if($status == 0)
            $str = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .  '/images/layout/dangTuyen/tick_icon_OK_black.png'.$status;
        else
            $str = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/layout/dangTuyen/tick_icon_green.png'.$status;

        $arr = array(
            'label' => 'Accept',
            'imageUrl' => $str,
            'htmlOption' => array('class' => 'imageIcon'),
            'click' => 'function(){}',
        );

        return $arr;
    }
```

I use gridview:

```
Controller::widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

    'id' => 'dang-tuyen-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
                 'accept' => $model->statusImageAccept('$data->status'),
));
```

When use `$model->statusImageAccept('$data->status')` then in function `statusImageAccept($status)`, var $status is string `$data->status`

How to use `$data`?

Comment: What is `statusImageAccept` supposed to return? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks you! This is function statusImageAccept($status) in model class `DangTuyen`

Comment: Yes, but how is the return value going to be used? What is it that has `label` and `imageUrl` properties?

Comment: This is `attribute` of `template` in [`CButtonColumn`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn)

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do there. The best way to actually do it is probably by extending `CButtonColumn`.

Comment: You have a question on Web Applications. Why don't you create an account over there an see if the answer give was helpful: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24902/29140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Controller::widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'dang-tuyen-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => '',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data) {
                $imageUrl = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .  '/images/layout/dangTuyen/';
                if (0 == $data->status) {
                    $imageUrl .= 'tick_icon_OK_black.png' . $data->status;
                } else {
                    $imageUrl .= 'tick_icon_green.png' . $data->status;
                }
                return CHtml::link(CHtml::image($imageUrl,'Accept'),$url, array(
                    'click' => 'function(){}',
                    'class' => 'imageIcon',
                ));
            }
        )
    )
);
```